# Configuring the value of [Today] in sharepoint

Tags: 2013, 2010, configuration

I am trying to change the time zone settings that `[Today]` should follow.

It is currently taking `UTC-8` and I want to change that to `UTC` timezone.

I tried changing the **regional settings**  timezone at site collection level to UTC and also **tried changing general settings in the web application level** in central admin.

I also tried changing the timezone of the server.
 But it is still following the UTC-8 timezone.

The issue I am facing is, if it is 9AM in UTC+5 time zone Today, then the value of `[Today]` will contain Yesterday's date and I want to change that. I am using it in search query rules